# How to display output from a MFC based application class file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface, mfc

I am a beginner to programming, I have made a MFC based GUI application and linked the variables by Cptr to a class file. Now i need to print the outputs of that class file. The outputs are variable values hence I am unable to display the string.

I had made a Output dialog box along with its class & header file, but am unable to transfer the values from one class to another and the values are not printed in the Output dialog box. I tried TRACE & OutputDebugString but I am unsuccessful,  I am not sure if transferring the values is a correct option.

Class file code:

```
std::cout << HV_Tmid_1 << std::endl;
std::cout << HV_Tmid_2 << std::endl;
std::cout << HV_Tmid_3 << std::endl;
std::cout << HV_Tmid_4 << std::endl;
std::cout << LV_Tmid_1 << std::endl;
std::cout << LV_Tmid_2 << std::endl;
std::cout << LV_Tmid_3 << std::endl;
std::cout << LV_Tmid_4 << std::endl;
```

Output Dialog Class Code:

```
// Output.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Thermal Tool.h"
#include "Output.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"
#include "TT.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


// Output dialog

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(Output, CDialog)

Output::Output(CWnd* pParent /*=nullptr*/)
    : CDialog(IDD_OUTPUT, pParent)

{
    m_d_hvmid1 = _T("");
    m_d_hvmid2 = _T("");
    m_d_hvmid3 = _T("");
    m_d_hvmid4 = _T("");
    m_d_lvmid1 = _T("");
    m_d_lvmid2 = _T("");
    m_d_lvmid3 = _T("");
    m_d_lvmid4 = _T("");
}

Output::~Output()
{

}

void Output::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_HV_MID1, m_d_hvmid1);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_HV_MID2, m_d_hvmid2);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_HV_MID3, m_d_hvmid3);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_HV_MID4, m_d_hvmid4);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_LV_MID1, m_d_lvmid1);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_LV_MID2, m_d_lvmid2);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_LV_MID3, m_d_lvmid3);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_LV_MID4, m_d_lvmid4);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Output, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// Output message handlers

void Output::AssignDlgToPtr1()
{
        m_d_hvmid1.Format(_T("%f"), Cptr.HV_Tmid_1);
        m_d_hvmid2.Format(_T("%f"), Cptr.HV_Tmid_2);
        m_d_hvmid3.Format(_T("%f"), Cptr.HV_Tmid_3);
        m_d_hvmid4.Format(_T("%f"), Cptr.HV_Tmid_4);
        m_d_lvmid1.Format(_T("%f"), Cptr.LV_Tmid_1);
        m_d_lvmid2.Format(_T("%f"), Cptr.LV_Tmid_2);
        m_d_lvmid3.Format(_T("%f"), Cptr.LV_Tmid_3);
        m_d_lvmid4.Format(_T("%f"), Cptr.LV_Tmid_4);

}
```

The Output is also shown empty due to

```
void CThermalToolDlg::OnCalculate()
{
    UpdateData();
    if (!Validate()) return;
    AssignDlgToPtr();
    Cptr.OnCalculate();
    // need to add something here to run Output Dialog class before displaying output box
    // AssignDlgToPtr1() is not a member in this class;
    Output Dlg;
    Dlg.DoModal();
    UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

I expect to print the string values in an output dialog box. If someone could provide me with a correct code or point me to a proper tutorial I would be thankful.

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: @Oliort I know I've been going wrong about this hence I didnt post the code

Comment: You're using comparison (==) and not assignation (=). There may be other problems too depending on what are the types of the `m_dhvid` members which you don't mention.

Comment: "The exchange and validation data map is written in an override of CWnd::DoDataExchange that is added to your new dialog class. See the DoDataExchange member function in CWnd for more on the exchange and validation functionality.

Both the programmer and the framework call DoDataExchange indirectly through a call to CWnd::UpdateData."

Quote from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class?view=vs-2019.

Comment: @acraig5075 I'm using comparison because the type is string, but my Cptr value is a double and I'm stuck in converting double to string.

Comment: Are m_d_... variables CStrings thens? If so, you could use m_d_hmvid1.Format( _T("%f"), Cptr.HV_Tmid_1 ); ...

Comment: The issue is resolved for string variables, but still the calculated variables are not getting transferred but only initial values are getting transferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that the members of `CPtr` are doubles. Assuming the `m_d_?vmid?` member variables are declared as `CString`, you could use:

```
void Output::AssignDlgToPtr1()
{
    m_d_hvmid1.Format( _T("%f"), Cptr.HV_Tmid_1 );
    m_d_hvmid2.Format( _T("%f"), Cptr.HV_Tmid_2 );
    m_d_hvmid3.Format( _T("%f"), Cptr.HV_Tmid_3 );
    m_d_hvmid4.Format( _T("%f"), Cptr.HV_Tmid_4 );
    m_d_lvmid1.Format( _T("%f"), Cptr.LV_Tmid_1 );
    m_d_lvmid2.Format( _T("%f"), Cptr.LV_Tmid_2 );
    m_d_lvmid3.Format( _T("%f"), Cptr.LV_Tmid_3 );
    m_d_lvmid4.Format( _T("%f"), Cptr.LV_Tmid_4 );
}
```

**UPDATE** after more code was added to the question:
`AddignDlgToPtr1()` is never called. The Dialog box don't know on it's own when to call it. Best way is probably to overwrite `OnInitDialog`:

```
BOOL Output::OnInitDialog()
{
   CDialog::OnInitDialog();

   AssignDlgToPtr1();

   UpdateData(FALSE);

   return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
   // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}
```

Alternatively, you could also overwrite the UpdateData(...) method, but as you only want to show the results and looks like you don't care for edits, the above way is easiest.

Further, "UpdateData(FALSE)" is executed in the caller code after the dialog is closed... That line of code is not required.

Another option is to change the calling code to:

```
void CThermalToolDlg::OnCalculate()
{
    UpdateData();
    if (!Validate()) return;
    AssignDlgToPtr();
    Cptr.OnCalculate();
    // need to add something here to run Output Dialog class before displaying output box
    // AssignDlgToPtr1() is not a member in this class;
    Output Dlg;
    Dlg.AssignDlgToPtr1();
    Dlg.DoModal();
    // UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

... assuming AddignDlgToPtr1() is public...

Comment: Thanks for correcting the faulty code, but the output dialog box still shows empty Edit control boxes with no value printed in it.

Comment: The code does'nt even reach to this function when I add a breakpoint. The dialog opens due to  Output Dlg; Dlg.DoModal(); but doesnt run the Output dialog class file

Comment: Well, then post the code that should do this! You probably need to connect the edit boxes to the variables (either using class wizard in Visual Studio, or manually in the DoDataExchange() method of your Dialog class. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/mfc/dialog-data-exchange?view=vs-2019). And if you "AssignDlgToPtr1()" is not called, you need to call it from your code somewhere.

Comment: DDX has been done for IDC to m_d_?vmid1, but the issue is code doesnt even run that script

Comment: Please post your complete class then! Your shared code does not contain any DDX code.

Comment: @Marco Freudenberger Kindly check the edited question

Comment: I forgot an UpdateData() call in the OnInitDialog. Updated the answer. It's been a while sicne I did MFC coding...

Comment: Still the output printed is 0.00000 becuase the Cptr.?V_Tmid_? values are initialized to zero in header file of calculation class. It doesnt print the calculated value.

Comment: OK, but's not the problem you posted here :-)

Comment: The  Cptr values transferred are zero, even I converted double values to string, but they too are not getting transferred as the calculated string, but empty string.